# How to avoid putting @RefreshScope on multiple beans in my application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

We are externalizing configuration of our microservices (spring boot based) using spring cloud.

As per my understanding on Spring Cloud, to enable the beans loading refreshed/updated values from **Config server** we need to do 2 things in **Spring Cloud Client**:

1. add `@RefreshScope` on the beans reading values from property files
   using `@Value`
2. add spring actuator to provide /refresh endpoint to
   refresh the context.

**Scenario**:
We have 100s of classes reading values from property file using @Value.
I have to mark all these beans refresh enabled using @RefreshScope annotation.

How can I avoid putting `@RefreshScope` annotation on all these classes.
Is there any shortcut or spring cloud feature to get around this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into Spring Boot feature called [`@ConfigurationProperties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties). It is designed to better organize several external configuration options.

According [this Github issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/519), it should work for spring-cloud without `@RefreshScope` usage.

EDIT (reaction on comment): Maybe you are missing point of `@ConfigurationProperties`. With this annotation, you wouldn't use it in other configuration classes. You would have dedicated class (or few classes) only for reading and providing properties. Other configuration classes would inject this configuration holder bean.

Comment: If I use @ConfigurationProperties in that case also, I need to put this annotation on all the classes that are reading properties. That is what I want to avoid. I am looking some feature using which I put this or any other annotation on some super class like SpringBootApplication.class and that takes care of refreshing all beans.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that if one confines configuration to @ConfigurationProperties beans, and then use that bean as a proxy for the values they will decrease the number of beans that will be reloaded by the application context.  Maybe you could provide a code sample to clearly demonstrate what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

You could encapsulate your `@Values` into one (or several)  ConfigurationService bean which is `@RefreshScoped` and autowire this service into your classes instead. That way you only have a small amount of request scoped beans and your services can stay singletons.

Comment: This approach sounds good, but this better suits at initial stage of developing the app. In cases like mine when I have entire app already developed and if I autowire one ConfigurationService in all the beans which are having @Value then anyways I would have to modify all those beans. That is what I want to avoid.

Comment: You can start now for the new implementations and refactor the existing ones one-by-one later. Both approaches should work at the same time.